# In JavaScript/Ajax, how can you get the value of the root element in an XMLDocument?

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

This should be something easy to look up, but any related documentation I see fails to work in this case.  Let's say you have a response coming back from a web service call with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello, World!  str=1</string>
```

I just want to be able to extract the value - Hello, World!  str=1 - without having to use string.replace() or anything else like that.  If the XML were stored in a variable called response, and if the following code were called:

```
alert(response.documentElement.nodeValue)
```

"undefined" is what shows up.  What the heck?  I just want to get a string or any sort of ordinary primitive out of a web method (I'm not using JSON or anything), but documentation on how to do this is being difficult to find.  How do you do this?  Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal str As Int32) As String
    Return "Hello, World!  str=" & str
End Function
```

---

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "&str=1",
            dataType: "xml",
            url: "<HTTP path and filename>.asmx/HelloWorld",
            timeout: 15000,
            cache:false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("bad");
            }
        });
    //-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows:

```
[object XMLDocument]
```

Comment: Please show more code around how you're getting `response`. It is most likely that `response` is not an `XMLDocument` object.

Comment: `response.documentElement.textContent` or `response.documentElement.firstChild.nodeValue` may be? Without a more comprehensive example, it is hard to give you a better answer.

Comment: Both of them worked, Ianzz.  Thanks.  Copy your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `response.documentElement.textContent` and `response.documentElement.firstChild.nodeValue` will give you the text content with the example XML documents you have provided.

Comment: Wow, sorry, I didn't see it when you copied into an answer earlier.